# UITableView inside UICollectionView handling touches.

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

Collection view consists of a single row, of horizontally aligned cells, which size is the same size as the collection view's bounds, single cell fills entire screen.

The problem is that the collection view seems to be intercepting all of the pans. How can I forward them to the table so I can also scroll the table vertically.

I want vertical pan to be delivered to the table inside the cell, so it can scroll up and down. I want horizontal pan to be delivered to the collection view, so it can scroll horizontally.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Use storyBoard,try to put tableView inside collectionViewCell.collectionView as subview of self.view

Comment: Collection view is a subview of a view already. Table view was inserted into prototype cell of a collection view, so during runtime its in, cell.contentView. Taps do get delivered to the table, I can see the cells inside getting selected.

Comment: Yes,drag tableView into cell square(cell.contenView). Show some code.

Comment: Yeah, thats what I have already. Doesn't seem to do the trick. There is no code really. I just do "return collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"sample" forIndexPath:indexPath]"

Comment: Don't forget delegate, datasource for tableView.Try display some tableCell and test.

Comment: Adding delegate/data source and displaying cell still does not help. I am pretty sure I have to override touch delivery or alter gesture recognisers, its just that I don't really know how.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For UITableView inside CollectionView using storyBoard, please follow these steps:

-Drag CollectionView to UIViewController, drag datasource to  UIViewController(don't drag delegate). Add datasource methods inside ViewController.m

-Create Cell:CollectionViewCell class. choose class for Cell in storyBoard to Cell class,specify reuse ID.

-Drag tableView inside collectionCell square. delegate, datasource drag to CollecionCell Square too. Add tableView datasource, delegate inside Cell.m

-Create CellDelegate when implement tableViewDidSelect inside it. Transfer this delegate to UIViewController to perform other action

Sample code: https://github.com/lequysang/github_zip/blob/master/TableViewInCollection.zip

Comment: So yeah that works, I forgot to mention, I am using custom layout, which is a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout. It seems to be the root of all problems.

Comment: Hi In the code if I increase the no of cell in the collection view. In the third cell of the collection view it is showing the first table view, not the third. How to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

Swift2 update - We don't need to do all the above steps. Just making the controller the delegate and datasource of both the tableview and collection view works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to make this work without using storyboards--although, I use XIBs for my views but only to add the Autolayout rules. All customisation (colors, fonts, labels, etc.) are set in code. In any case, this should also work for cells that are being built programatically.

How to do it:

- The most important thing to remember is to **add your custom view to the `contentView` property of the cell** and **not inside the cell itself**. If you are using XIBs for the custom `UICollectionViewCell`, leave it blank. Instantiate your custom view (where the `UITableView` is), then add it as a subview of the `UICollectionViewCell`'s `contentView`. If you add the table vie directly inside the collection view cell, *the table view will not vertically scroll*.
- Implement `shouldSelectItemAtIndexPath` and `shouldHighlightItemAtIndexPath` of the `UICollectionViewDelegate` and make both return `false`, so that tapping on the collection view cell does not intercept with taps intended for the table view inside.

Done with Xcode 7.3 for iOS 9+.

Comment: can you share your demo?