# UITableView inside custom UICollectionView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uicollectionview

As the title says, i'm trying to put one UITableView inside a custom UICollectionViewCell, i made it so it's perfectly displayed, but now i need the touches inside the Cell that contains the Table to call the didSelectRowForIndexPath method.

I have a .xib for this custom UICollectionViewCell, inside it i have the UITableView, and i have it's delegate and datasource correctly set.
Now, if i run this, the CollectionView cells are loaded with their proper data (this is, each cell with a table containing the proper rows), but if i try to select one row from one table, the CollectionViewCell is selected instead of the TableViewCell (this is expected, but not what i need).

I'd like to know if is there a way for the TableView row to get selected, even if it's inside a CollectionView cell.

Thank you and sorry for my english.

Comment: Conceptually it should be doable. I've embedded uitableviews inside uitableview rows, so I don't see why it wouldn't work as you've done. Maybe you set a bool to disable the selection of the cell if a uitable is present inside it?

Comment: i tested with ``[cell setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];`` but it didn't work, where you thinking of something different to disable the cell selection?

Comment: disabling user interaction completely would disable touches to the table as well, so not exactly what I was thinking. I'm *assuming* that didselectcell has some event for the other cells. That's where I might consider shortcircuiting things in the event that a tableview was present.

Comment: Yes, some cells don't have a table inside, and i need them to call didselectcell.

Comment: This looks like great answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15193789/1162044

Comment: No i didn't, but I left that project a while ago so it doesn't matter anymore. Thank you anyway!